# In VS Code, why do I have two action buttons for opening a Markdown Preview that have different results?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, preview

I'm trying to use a custom CSS to improve my markdown writing and reading. But some configurations is weird on my VS Code.

I edited my settings to add my css:

```json
"markdown.styles": ["./meu-boilerplate.css"]
```

if I press "ctrl+shift+v" it does preview the file, but with no styling:

[image]

But if I press the "Open Preview to the Side" button, it does work:

[image]

[image]

Two things to notice:

1. At the first preview screenshot that is not working, notice that the screen name reads  "Preview: 'Preview: 'filename'', and on the screenshot that is working, only "Preview filename" is shown;
2. I highlighted the button area, and there are 2 "open preview" buttons. The one to the left opens the correct renderized preview, and the one to the right, opens the wrong one.

I disabled all markdown extentions, looked at default setting json and workspace json files, but I can't find any weird key deffinition. The only markdon definition is on the default file: `{ "key": "ctrl+shift+v", "command": "markdown.showPreview", "when": "!notebookEditorFocused && editorLangId == 'markdown'" },`

I'm lost here... I just wanted to see my markdown file rendered with my CSS when I press ctrl+shift+v, but it brings the no rendered one... Anyone got this issue?

Side note: I did try the "Markdown Preview Enhanced" extension, it's cool, but it's not easy to import my own CSS file on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the second button is caused/contributed by an extension. In this particular case, for example, the issue was found by [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to be caused by the [`searKing.preview-vscode`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=searKing.preview-vscode) extension (just one of several Markdown Preview extension in the extension marketplace).

The normal behaviour in VS Code is like this: There is only one action button for Markdown Preview. Clicking is to open preview to the side (<kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>v</kbd>), and holding <kbd>alt</kbd> while clicking opens the preview in new editor tab (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>). This behaviour is described in the tooltip of the action button.